# How do I rate limit push notifications through AWS SNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

We need to be able to broadcast messages to all our users without overwhelming our database with a huge spike in users coming in all at once. I see there is a way under AWS SNS to rate limit messages going to a single subscribed endpoint, but I do not see a way to rate limit messages going to an application. Ideally, it would be great to have a way to say "Max Endpoints/Sec == 1000"

Comment: Pretty sure there's no way to do this in the way you want.  I send one message at a time so if I wanted to rate limit that would be something I'd be able to do, but usually I'm trying to send them all as quickly as possible.

Comment: @Krum Understood. Normally, many would want to send as fast as possible, but when you are hosting, this causes a massive spike in DB usage and general wonkiness as lambda nodes or EC2 instances are spinning up. Would be a great feature. I may resort to pushing from our Dynamo table manually from our dev server